# Brightcove video not responsive on orientation change on mobile

Tags: javascript, video, brightcove

I have a brightcove video on my site. My site is responsive and hence I expect the player should be responsive too. Now, I have gone through the Brightcove documentation on 'responsive sizing for video players'. Here's the link:
http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/smart-player-api/samples/responsive-sizing.html

However, it doesn't work for my video. I also created a test page on my site where I copy pasted their sample code, but even that failed. When I open their sample page on mobile everything works fine. But the same code fails on my site.

Also, I suspect that the *onTemplateLoad* and *onTemplateReady* events do not fire as I get an error saying "*experienceModule* is undefined" on window resize.

I am providing the sample code below:

```
<style type="text/css">
 .containing-block {
      width: 75%;
     }
    .outer-container {
      position: relative;
      height: 0;
      padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    }
    .BrightcoveExperience {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }</style>
<div class="containing-block" id="container2"><div class="outer-container"    id="container1"><!-- Start of Brightcove Player --><div style="display:none">&nbsp;</div><!--
        By use of this code snippet, I agree to the Brightcove Publisher T and C 
        found at https://accounts.brightcove.com/en/terms-and-conditions/. 
        -->
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"    src="http://admin.brightcove.com/js/BrightcoveExperiences.js"></script>

<script src="http://admin.brightcove.com/js/APIModules_all.js"></script>

<object class="BrightcoveExperience" id="myExperience1754276221001">
<param name="includeAPI" value="true" /><param name="templateLoadHandler" value="onTemplateLoaded" /><param name="templateReadyHandler" value="onTemplateReady" /><param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" /><param name="width" value="480" /><param name="height" value="270" /><param name="playerID" value="1785957921001" /><param name="playerKey" value="AQ~~,AAABmA9XpXk~,-Kp7jNgisrdzE4WB9lhVzM13pYBWmmbj" /><param name="isVid" value="true" /><param name="isUI" value="true" /><param name="dynamicStreaming" value="true" /><param name="@videoPlayer" value="1754276221001" /></object><script src="//docs.brightcove.com/en/scripts/https-fix.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">brightcove.createExperiences();</script></div></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var player,
      APIModules,
      videoPlayer,
      experienceModule;

    function onTemplateLoaded(experienceID){
      console.log("EVENT: onTemplateLoad");
      player = brightcove.api.getExperience(experienceID);
      APIModules = brightcove.api.modules.APIModules;
    }

    function onTemplateReady(evt){
      console.log("EVENT.onTemplateReady");
      videoPlayer = player.getModule(APIModules.VIDEO_PLAYER);
      experienceModule = player.getModule(APIModules.EXPERIENCE);
      videoPlayer.play();

      videoPlayer.getCurrentRendition( function (renditionDTO) {

         var newPercentage = ( renditionDTO.frameHeight / renditionDTO.frameWidth ) * 100;
         newPercentage = newPercentage + "%";
         console.log("Video Width = "+renditionDTO.frameWidth+" and Height = "+renditionDTO.frameHeight);
         console.log("New Percentage = "+newPercentage);
         document.getElementById("container1").style.paddingBottom = newPercentage;
      });
 var evt = document.createEvent('UIEvents');
evt.initUIEvent('resize',true,false,0);
window.dispatchEvent(evt);
videoPlayer.play();
    }
 function calulateNewPercentage(width,height) {
logit("function", "calulateNewPercentage");
var newPercentage = ((height / width) * 100) + "%";
logit("Video Width = ", width);
logit("Video Height = ", height);
logit("New Percentage = ", newPercentage);
document.getElementById("container1").style.paddingBottom = newPercentage;
}
 window.onresize = function(evt) {
var $=jQuery;
var resizeWidth = $(".BrightcoveExperience").width(),
resizeHeight = $(".BrightcoveExperience").height();
if (experienceModule.experience.type == "html"){
experienceModule.setSize(resizeWidth, resizeHeight)
//logit("html mode: ", "call setSize method to resize player");
   }
  }

      </script>
```

I am really at a loss and any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue and solved it with some Javascript that uses the resize event only on HTML5 experiences.

```
foo = (function() {
    var players = []
    return {
        onTemplateLoad: function(id) {
            players.push(id);
    },
        onTemplateReady: function(event) {
            var player = brightcove.api.getExperience(event.target.experience.id);
            var videoPlayer = player.getModule(brightcove.api.modules.APIModules.VIDEO_PLAYER);
            var experienceModule = player.getModule(brightcove.api.modules.APIModules.EXPERIENCE);

            if (experienceModule.experience.type == "html") {
                window.addEventListener("resize", function(event) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
                        var resizeWrapper = $('.js-video-container');
                        var resizeWidth = resizeWrapper.innerWidth();
                        var resizeHeight = resizeWrapper.innerHeight();
                        experienceModule.setSize(resizeWidth, resizeHeight)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}())
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I ran into the same problem. Brightcove's example worked fine for me on desktop browsers, but once I started testing on iOS and Android, I saw that the preview window (with the big 'play' triangle icon) would not resize when I rotated the screen from portrait to landscape and vice versa.  The solution I came up with is not truly responsive, but it does resize the preview window in iOS and Android based on screen width.  It basically involves a lot of media queries!

Here is an example of two videos with all the CSS and JS included:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row_video">
    <div class="containing-block">
        <div class="outer-container">
            <div class="video_1"></div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row_video" style="margin-top:50px;">
     <div class="containing-block">
        <div class="outer-container">
            <div class="video_2"></div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.row_video { 
width:100%;
display:block;
margin:0 auto; }

.row_video:after { 
    clear:both; 
    content:""; 
    display:table; }

.containing-block { 
    width:100%; }
.outer-container { 
    position:relative; 
    padding-bottom:56.25%; 
    height:0; }
.BrightcoveExperience { 
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; }

@media screen and (max-width: 950px) {
    .row_video { width:650px; } }

@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
    .row_video { width:450px; } }

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .row_video { width:320px; } }
```

**JS** - For the purposes of this test, paste these at the bottom of your HTML.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    brightcove.createExperiences();
</script>
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://admin.brightcove.com/js/BrightcoveExperiences.js"></script>

<script>
    $(".video_1").html('<object id="myExperience1754276206001" class="BrightcoveExperience"><param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" /><param name="width" value="480" /><param name="height" value="270" /><param name="playerID" value="1753810340001" /><param name="playerKey" value="AQ~~,AAABmA9XpXk~,-Kp7jNgisrdihurn3hYnYJWo8k_gM6uF" /><param name="isVid" value="true" /><param name="isUI" value="true" /><param name="dynamicStreaming" value="true" /><param name="@videoPlayer" value="1754276206001" /></object>');
</script>

<script>
    $(".video_2").html('<object id="myExperience1754276205001" class="BrightcoveExperience"><param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" /><param name="width" value="480" /><param name="height" value="270" /><param name="playerID" value="1756040703001" /><param name="playerKey" value="AQ~~,AAABmA9XpXk~,-Kp7jNgisrc05QYSNxkzqM1X9GtvaqWM" /><param name="isVid" value="true" /><param name="isUI" value="true" /><param name="dynamicStreaming" value="true" /><param name="@videoPlayer" value="1754276205001" /></object>');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these parameters to your object element at the end:

```
<param name="includeAPI" value="true" />
<param name="templateLoadHandler" value="onTemplateLoaded" />
<param name="templateLoadHandler" value="onTemplateLoad" />
<param name="templateReadyHandler" value="onTemplateReady" />
```

Answer (score 0):

What `doctype` did your site have? It appears that the HTML5 doctype of `<!DOCTYPE html>` performs better than others. Also, if you have any `viewport` meta tags set that maybe interfering with the scale.

Actually it appears simply removing `maximum-scale=1.0,initial-scale=1.0` from the `<meta name="viewport" ...>` tag helps.

Answer (score 0):

try javascript solution

```
var $video =  $(".vjs")[0];

function videoJsReady() {
    var player = this;

    var _resize = function() {
        var ratio = 967/486; // your video aspect ratio
        var width = $(window).width();
        var height = width / ratio;
        $($video).css('width', width);
        $($video).css('height', height);
    };

    $(window).on('orientationchange', function(){
        _resize();
    });

    _resize();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented what is described here, http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/smart-player-api/samples/responsive-sizing.html,  under "HTML Mode" section and succeeded. In short, Brightcove html5 based player does not come being responsive on its own, we will have to add our own js code to utilize Brightcove API setSize() method to make it work.